# Django - array of checkboxes

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, checkbox, django-models

I would like to out a number of checkboxes in one of my templates and I can't get it to work.

I'm trying to pass an array containing forms.BooleanField() in my form like :

```
class ProjetSettingsForm(forms.Form):

    ## A bunch of form fields of no interest

    arrayCheck = []
    cb1 = forms.BooleanField()
    cb2 = forms.BooleanField()
    arrayCheck.append(cb1)
    arrayCheck.append(cb2)
```

and output it like this in my template

```
{% for a in form.arrayCheck %}
{{ a }}
{% endfor %}
```

My form is called by a view :

```
def settings(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and (request.POST.get("settings_task_type", "") == "Enregistrer Task Type"):
                form = ProjetSettingsForm(request.POST, proj_id=request.session['proj'])
                if form.is_valid():
                        settings = form.save_task_type()
                        c = {'proj':proj, 'form':form, 'settings':settings}
                        return render_to_response('projet/settings.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

        else:
                form = ProjetSettingsForm(proj_id=request.session['proj'])
                settings = ""

        c = {'proj':proj, 'form':form, 'settings':settings}
        return render_to_response('projet/settings.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But it displays :

```
<django.forms.fields.BooleanField object at 0xb595a2ec> <django.forms.fields.BooleanField object at 0xb595a22c>
```

How can I get it to display the checkboxes correctly ?

The reason I need to pass the checkboxes as an array and not one by one is that there will be many of them and I won't know in advance their exact number, it depends on a sql query.

**EDIT:**

If someone comes across this post, i found a solution. I don't use a form when I need to pass an array of checkboxes.

I send the array directly from my view, create the checkboxes in the template and get the results in `request.POST.getlist('my_array')`

Answer (score 3):

Don't use form fields outside a form. They don't work like that. Create a form with a MultipleChoiceField.

Comment: What do you mean by that ? I created the fields inside a form

Comment: No you didn't. They're in a list. Use a Django form class.

Comment: They are in a class `class ProjetSettingsForm(forms.Form):  ` I just didn't put it in my question

Comment: Then what's `arrayCheck`? This makes no sense without seeing the full code.

Comment: It's a variable of the Form class. I know I'm making something wrong, but I don't know what

Comment: Seriously, please show the full code of the form and the view. I can't help otherwise.